# Arbitrary evaluation in the type signature in agda

Tags: agda, function-signature

So I have another "simple" Adga question.  I wanted to have a proof that used arbitrary evaluations as premises and results.  But I don't think I know the type system well enough to do that.

as a simple example take

```
f : {S : Set} -> (a : S) 
 -> ( R : S -> Set) 
 -> (R a)
f aa rr = rr aa
```

which has a compilation error

```
Set !=< rr aa of type Set1
when checking that the expression rr aa has type rr aa
```

of course

```
f : {S : Set} -> (a : S) 
 -> ( R : S -> Set) 
 -> Set
f aa rr = rr aa
```

compiles fine

as does

```
f : {S : Set} -> (a : S) 
 -> ( R : S -> Set) 
 -> (R a)
 -> (R a)
f _ _ ra = ra
```

What does `(R a)` means in context?  Can it be constructed?  How can it be constructed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example the expression `rr aa` has type `Set`, because it is the result of the application of `aa` of type `S` to the function `rr` of type `S -> Set`.

The type signature of your function demands a result type of `R a` though. Given the naming of your parameters the expected result type is `rr aa`. The type checker now tries to unify the expected type (`rr aa`) with the expression type (`Set`) and fails.

In fact a function of the type given above would be inconsistent with the type theory:

```
no-f : (f : {S : Set} → (a : S) → (R : S → Set) → R a) → ⊥
no-f f = f tt (λ _ → ⊥)
```

In other words, assuming there was a function of the type above, an element of the empty type (⊥) could be produced. So in general you cannot construct elements of type `R a` without additional requirements.

Imports used above:

```
open import Data.Empty
open import Data.Unit
```